# PHP: File upload array is Empty.

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, file-upload, nativedroid

I've a form for adding user to my database and it also uploads an image to my site, this all works fine. I am using http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/ as my site is for mobiles.

The problem is when I include this line on the php page with the form:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

This causes $_FILES to be empty. Even if I simplify the form to this the $_FILES array is empty.

This is my simple form:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="myfile"><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Staff"></p>         
</form>
```

When I echo this in my upload.php

```
$name = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
```

I get an undefined error for "name", because the array is empty.

For some reason including the jquery is emptying the array, but I can't find a solution. I've been stuck on this for days now so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think js can empty your server $_FILES array, try to do  `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: when i do that it just prints an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think js conflict will be there so your code will not working there and you are getting empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Change form code .. please check submit tag..

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="myfile"><p>
    <input type="submit" name="anyname" value="Add Staff"></p>         
</form>
```

hope this help!

Comment: That didn't work. I got it working kind of just using an iframe on the page. looks a bit weird but does the job. Thanks for trying though, I appreciate it.